# Zsh: force file/folder obey new umask

Tags: zsh, umask

Default zsh shell uses `umask` `0022`, when changing to new `umask`, e.g: `0077`.

Only new file/folders after changing to new `umask` are applied.

How to use zsh/or-else to force old file/folder create under current user obey newly changed `umask`?

Comment: You need to use the `chmod` command to change existing (old) files and folders (directories)

Comment: The `umask` is a property of a process, it has little to do with shells (other than shells often have a `umask` builtin command to set the `umask` of their own process (and as a result of every child process they spawn)).

Comment: `zsh` (or any shell)  doesn't set the `umask` by default. It has already been set for it on startup. On Linux, Pluggable Authentication Modules can set it (based on configuration in `/etc/login.defs` for instance). Users can also choose to alter it in their `.profile` or `.zshrc` by invoking the `umask` builtin command.

Comment: Yes, I've just use `find` and change perms on file or directory, at the end, only user files that need to be change perm, other the /home directory root take owner so we don't have to worry much.